# Reverse DNS for my mailserver returns the (seemingly) wrong information

Tags: dns, reverse-dns, email-server

When I run `$ dig my-domain.tld` I get the correct IP address, but when I run `$ dig mail.my-domain.tld` I get back something that looks like this:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
my-domain.tld.      600 IN SOA ns03.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. numbersnumbernumbers
```

I definitely recognize `ns03.domaincontrol.com` as one of my DNS provider's default name servers, and I thought setting up an MX record would (should?) point rDNS queries to the IP address associated with my A record. I do have the reverse DNS set up with my cloud provider.  What do I need to do to get `dig mail.my-domain.tld` to return the same address as `dig my-domain.tld`?

Update 23-04-2020:  RedGrittyBrick is essentially correct, although I still don't quite know how to write or use a zone file.  I've managed to resolve my DNS issues by altering the MX record with my DNS provider by doing two things.  1) I've added an A record for `mail.my-domain.tld`, and, 2) I've altered the MX record from `mail.my-domain.tld` to `my-domain.tld`.  I'm now sending and receiving mail without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to do to get dig mail.my-domain.tld to return the same address as dig my-domain.tld?

Add an `A` record for `mail` into the zone file for `my-domain.tld`.

> I thought setting up an MX record would (should?) point rDNS queries to the IP address associated with my A record.

The `MX` record doesn't do what you think it does. It tells other people's SMTP servers where to send mail addressed to someone@my-domain.tld. It does not create any associations between hostnames and addresses - you need `A` and `PTR` records for that.